# About the star order when two random variables have proportional quantile functions

Tags: calculus, probability, probability-theory

I'm investigating about some relations between random variables through stochastic orders.

In particular, I have to prove the following thing:

"Let $F$ and $G$ be respectively the cdfs of the random variables $U$ e $V$. Both the relations $U \leq_{*} V$ and $V \leq_{*} U$ hold simultaneously, and then we write $U=_{*}V$, if the random variables $U$ and $V$ have proportional quantile functions."

The quantile functions are $F^{-1}$ and $G^{-1}$.

If they're proportional, then
$$
F^{-1}=aG^{-1},
$$

where $a$ is a constant and $a \neq 0$.

I know also that $U$ is smaller than $V$ in the star order, with $U$ and $V$ nonegative, and write $U \leq_{*} V$, if and only if $G^{-1}$ is starshaped in x, or equivalently
$$
\frac{G^{-1}(F(x))}{x} \qquad \text{is increasing in $x$ on the support of $F(x)$}.
$$

MY IDEA

Because $U$ and $V$ have proportional quantile functions, then I could write:

$$
F^{-1}=aG^{-1}, \quad a \neq 0.
$$

When $U \leq_{*} V$, then
$$
\frac{G^{-1}(F(x))}{x}=\frac{\frac{1}{a}F^{-1}(F(x))}{x}=\frac{1}{a}
$$

than is constant in $x$.

When $U \geq_{*} V$, then
$$
\frac{G^{-1}(F(x))}{x}=\frac{aF^{-1}(F(x))}{x}=a.
$$

Does this prove the result I have to prove?